# Separate Address for Page Inside a Page

Tags: language-agnostic

I am somewhat new to web development, so I'm not sure how "stupid" this question is, but I couldn't find much when searching, so I wanted to ask.

I am creating a page that, when a user presses an Export button, it exports a snapshot of the site as a PDF.  The PDF library takes a URL.  That works well.  However, I want this page inside a larger site.  When I print, however, I don't want the larger site to be printed.  Is there a way to supply an "internal" HTML address so that my web page can still be accessed.  What should I look at to do something like this?

Thanks.

Comment: Is your application in PHP, .NET, other?

Comment: Also, is this "export" traversing links on your site and creating a single PDF, or is it an export of the current page the user is on?

Comment: @jheddings - .NET (with Javascript). The export is just doing the current page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to "hide" the rest of the page when the user prints a web page is to create a print stylesheet and include it in the page header like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="print.css" media="print">
```

Then simply hide the elements of the page that you don't want printing in your print.css file.

Comment: Yeah, that is a nice approach... And more portable than my `print=1`. The only drawback is that the printing library has to honor the CSS.  Still, +1.

Answer (score 0):

I'm wondering if by "larger site" you mean the template surrounding your content.  Is that true?  If so, a common approach is to provide a parameter that can be added to your request, like `print=1`, which would suppress the outer template when delivering your content.